# Code BEFORE thread.sleep(5000) never seems to happen

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have coded to change an image, then sleep for 5 seconds, then call some other code.

I'm expecting to see the changed image for 5 seconds, then the next bit of code will clear some text boxes and change the image again. but i never see the first change in my browser.

```
    sqlConnection.Close();
    imgCheck.ImageUrl = "../images/GreenCheck.jpg";//never shows
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    resetforms();
```

If i try and put the sleep in the resetforms(); call, it does the same thing.

```
sqlConnection.Close();
imgCheck.ImageUrl = "../images/GreenCheck.jpg";//never shows
resetforms();


public void resetforms()
{

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    txtboxVisitorCode.ReadOnly = false;
    txtboxPlateNumber.Text = "";
    txtboxResidentName.Text = "";
    txtboxVisitorCode.Text = "";
    txtboxVisitorName.Text = "";
    txtboxPlateNumber.Text = "";
    txtboxVisitorName.Text = "";
    imgCheck.ImageUrl = "../images/Blank.jpg";
```

I never see ../images/GreenCheck.jpg

thanks

Comment: You can't do that.  You need to understand the difference between the server and the client.

Comment: Is there a way I can have this same effect?

Comment: @birddseedd You will need to implement this on the client-side (i.e. in the browser). You will be using JavaScript and Ajax, so read up on them :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more details?
Are you running asp.net webapp and could you show the code that triggers the piece of code you implemented in the question?

Try adding runat=server property on your trigger. 
For example, I have a button that changes an image and it is implemented in html as:
     `<asp:Button ID="Button_AddServer" runat="server"`